# Head of a custom section

Tags: sectioning, report

I am creating a new section called `\tsubsection` taking over code practically 1:1 from `subsection` with the intention to introduce some modifications.

In this example

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{tsubsection}
%\renewcommand{\thetsubsection}{\@Roman\c@tsubsection}                                                                                                                                                      
\newcommand\tsubsection{\@startsection{tsubsection}{2}{\z@}%                                                                                                                                                
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%                                                                                                                                    
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%                                                                                                                                                   
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
%\newcommand*\l@tsubsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.2em}}                                                                                                                                               
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tsubsection{Methods}
Some text
\end{document}
```

the output is

[image]

Where does the extra "Methods" in the head of `tsubsection` come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra `Methods` shows up because you didn't define `\tsubsectionmark`, then the command:

```
\csname tsubsectionmark\endcsname{Methods}
```

(which shows up somewhere deep in the definition of `\@startsection`) becomes:

```
\relax{Methods}
```

which writes `Methods` to the PDF.

You have to define the `\tsubsectionmark` to add some page marking (with `\markright` or `\markboth`) or to simply consume the argument:

```
\newcommand\tsubsectionmark[1]{}
```

> [image]

Working code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{trace}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{tsubsection}
%\renewcommand{\thetsubsection}{\@Roman\c@tsubsection}
\newcommand\tsubsection{\@startsection{tsubsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\tsubsectionmark[1]{}
%\newcommand*\l@tsubsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tsubsection{Methods}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is `\@startsection` defined? I don't see its definition in report.cls. Why  don't I see the definition of `\subsectionmark` in report.cls?

Comment: `\@startsection` is defined in `latex.ltx` (but actually the `\csname tsubsectionmark\endcsname` thingy appears in `\@sect`, also defined in `latex.ltx`, which is called by `\@startsection`). `\subsectionmark` (and for other sectioning levels) are also in `latex.ltx`: `\let\subsectionmark\@gobble`.